# Input text is disappear when it button is clicked

Tags: jquery, validation, input, field

I am trying to validate the input field but the input filed text is disappear on click. Please help me out what is my mistake. thanks

```
<input type="text" class="a" />

<button id="test">Continue</button>

<div class="b">error msg </div>

$('#test').on('click', function () {
    if ($('.a').val('')) {
        $('.b').show();
    } else {
        $('.b').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5o93vvqz/1/

Comment: `if($('.a').val().length ==0)`

Comment: I also appreciate all other friends as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're setting the value to empty in the `if` statement instead of getting it.

`$('.a').val('')` will set the value of `.a` to empty string. To get the value use `$('.a').val()`.

Change `if ($('.a').val('')) {` to `if ($('.a').val() == '') {`

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/5o93vvqz/4/)

```js
$('#test').on('click', function() {
  if ($('.a').val() == '') {
    $('.b').show();
  } else {
    $('.b').hide();
  }
});
```

```css
.a {
  border: black solid 1px;
}
.b {
  display: none;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="a" />
<button id="test">Continue</button>
<div class="b">error msg</div>
```

**Shorter Version:**

```
$('#test').on('click', function () {
    $('.b').toggle(!(!!$('.a').val()));
});
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/5o93vvqz/3/)

Answer (score 0):

If u see output of $('.a') on console, you will find that its an array. So you need to read first element and get first value as below

```
var test = $('.a')[0];
$(test).val() // this will be the value of textbox
```